# Value from previous record each id

Tags: mysql

I have employee database , The salary isn't fixed

Table contains (employee_id - Date - Salary)

i want to show in the query  for each employee

```
employee_id    Previous_month_salary    current salary
```

How can i do it in sql?

Thanks very much

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: In MySQL specifically?

Comment: In what language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LEAD function:

```
SELECT employee_id, LAG(current_salary) OVER (ORDER BY current_salary) 
previous_month_salary, current_salary
```

Comment: Work well , Thanks my dear

Comment: How can i make it for single row i want last month only  please